# How to stop Gxt TextBox KeyPress event in FF as it is working on IE

Tags: keypress, gxt, onkeypress

In IE when the 'KeyPress' Event is not calling on pressing of navigation keys, but in FF it is firing the 'KeyPress' Event, how to stop this.
I am using Gxt 'TextField' with KeyPress event as follows

```
firstNameField.addListener(Events.KeyPress, getKeyPressListener());

private Listener<FieldEvent> getKeyPressListener(){
    return new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
        public void handleEvent(FieldEvent be) {
             char key = getChar(be.getEvent());
             if (!((key+"").matches("^[A-Za-z \\'\\-\\&]+$"))) {
                 be.stopEvent();
             }
        }
        // needed due to GWT 2.1 changes
        private native char getChar(NativeEvent e) /*-{
            return e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        }-*/;
    };
}
```

I have configured some regular expression which allows user to enter only 'A-Za-z','-' and '&', other than these values it stops the user from entering.

This code is working fine in IE, as it is not firing 'KeyPress' event on navigation key press, but when it comes to FF 'KeyPress' event is firing on every key hit. So to make 'FF' to work as similar to 'IE'